# What can device access on my iPhone through Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, ios

I would like to connect my iPhone to a rented car but would also like to control what the car can access on my iPhone.

I could not find any information on what is possible for the car to access on my phone? I have disabled Siri on my phone so I think the car could not access it. But can I control the rest? Only giving access to audio and calls and contacts?
I am afraid the car could access some Fotos or use mobile data or „attack“ my phone if the car software is manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any citations for this, but a BT connection to a car is pretty much only the BT details - it will remember the phone next time; that's it. All anyone can leech from that is the Phone's name.

I've rented many a vehicle with a whole list of phone names over the years. People forget to tell it to forget afterwards, but there's no real danger.

I have my own car linked as both BT & plug-in CarPlay to both my & my partner's phones. Neither of us has access to anything the other has done or used, just the phone's name in the BT list.

Any in-car device such as CarPlay is really just a remote screen to the phone itself - almost no real data passes between the two, other than remembering how you like your screen setup etc. which map you prefer...